# get the port number from linux server of postgre database

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have a database created in alinux server . I am trying to connect to the databse using SQL developer .It is asking for portnumber and i seem to have no idea of it.

Is there any way to get the port number of the PostGRE DB using linux command.

Answer (score 2):

5432 is the default port for postgres, try this one.

If still its not working try to see the port configured in the /etc configuration file /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf

Or take a look at all the ports open with the netstat -a command and grep for postgres